# Comments in QGIS Graphical Modeller

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

Is there a neat and tidy way of adding comments, or text boxes, into the display of the Graphical Modeller of QGIS 3.14 for a model that one is building.

This is straightforward in ArcGIS ModelBuilder but I can't find a neat way of doing this in the QGIS process model building tool.

Comment: @ Taras Thanks for this. Yes, this will be useful. I was hoping for something that would enable me to place comments directly in the model interface, which maybe isn't currently available

Answer (score 4):

I have found a way of doing what I want. Not sure how I missed this. I just right-click on a process box and Add comment .. or for an output box I click on the three dots bottom right of the box

Both cases then just add the comment I/you want. In the VIEW tab (top left) ensure show comments is ticked on.